# select object which has same one property and different another

Tags: c#, .net, linq

One `Transaction` has list of `TransactionMembers`. this list always contains two items.

One `TransactionMember` has `Transaction`, `Role` of type `RoleEnum` RoleEnum has only two values (Admin and Editor)

I want to select transaction member which has same transaction and role `RoleEnum.Admin`

inside method I'm getting transactionmember as parameter

```
public static Transaction SetTransaction(Transaction t, TransactionMember tm)
{
   if(tm.Role == TransactionMember.RoleEnum.Editor)
   { 
      ...
   }
   else
   {
      TransactionMember admin = (from t.Members.Where(x=>x.Transaction))
   }
}
```

Comment: `Transaction` contains `TransactionMembers`, and a `TransactionMember` contains a `Transaction`?

Comment: @Jonesy I guess it's something like: `class Owner { public IEnumerable<Thing> Things { get; set; } } class Thing { public Owner Owner { get; set; } }`

Comment: And circular references are always hard to work with.

Comment: @Leri how this contribute in resolving my question ?

Comment: @panjo I've just suggested rethinking your class architecture. :)

Comment: @Leri Thanks for your time, but my transaction is owner which hold list of member, where one member has owner which is transacton in my case. The way I see is the same, correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 TransactionMember admin = t.Members.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Transaction.Equals(t) 
                                                      && x.Role == RoleEnum.Admin));
```

If you know there should be at most one admin, use `SingleOrDefault` instead of `FirstOrDefault`.

If you know there should be exactly one admin (not 0 or more than 1), use `Single` instead of `FirstOrDefault`.